# Multiple Git push in one command

Tags: bash, git, github

I've an application that requires to run `git add`/`commit`/`push` on each single file i'd like to push, in order to trigger a Gitlab Job on each.

My problem is that git is actually taking many time to do the `git push` command.

Here are the commands i'm using:

```
git add myFile.json
git commit myFile.json -m "commitMessage"
variable1 = git rev-parse HEAD  # Storing last commit hash into a variable
# Pushing only one specific commit to (maybe) make it faster
git push $variable1:master
```

What i'd like to do is to make the whole process "faster".
What i've thought about:

- Doing multiple pipeline triggers using only one `git push` (maybe by running the pipeline on each commit instead of each push), but it doesn't seem possible.
- Doing multiple pushes in one `git push` command, so it doesn't have to reload some of the `git push` init operations before each file pushed (i have no idea on what is happenning during the `git push` process, so that idea may be wrong)

Does anyone has an idea on how to make this process faster, by using one of my ideas, or even a brand new one from you !

Note: I'm using HTTPS, so SSH solutions probably won't fit here.

Output of push command:

```
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 521 bytes | 521.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://gitlab/root/xxx.git
   bd0a7c1..9671b26  master -> master
```

Thanks in advance !

***Edit 1:***

Here is the output of `GIT_TRACE=true GIT_TRACE_PACKET=true git push`

```
12:47:38.387505 git.c:418               trace: built-in: git push https://root:password@gitlab/root/xxx.git
12:47:38.405394 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git-remote-https https://root:password@gitlab/root/xxx.git https://root:password@gitlab/root/xxx.git
12:47:39.926614 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< # service=git-receive-pack
12:47:39.926654 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0000
12:47:39.926664 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 4a902e3cdd3c06ba7fe9aa0345e510ce7c7ebb73 refs/heads/master\0report-status report-status-v2 delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta push-options object-format=sha1 agent=git/2.33.1.gl3
12:47:39.926678 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0000
12:47:39.931365 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
12:47:39.934089 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> 0000
12:47:39.934131 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git send-pack --stateless-rpc --helper-status --thin --progress https://root:password@gitlab/root/xxx.git/ --stdin
12:47:39.954005 git.c:418               trace: built-in: git send-pack --stateless-rpc --helper-status --thin --progress https://root:password@gitlab/root/xxx.git/ --stdin
12:47:39.962814 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
12:47:39.962841 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0000
12:47:39.965723 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 4a902e3cdd3c06ba7fe9aa0345e510ce7c7ebb73 refs/heads/master\0report-status report-status-v2 delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta push-options object-format=sha1 agent=git/2.33.1.gl3
12:47:39.965792 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0000
12:47:39.998180 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> shallow 67769ed9405583783a372dc7731d5c1be8801a63
12:47:39.998324 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> 4a902e3cdd3c06ba7fe9aa0345e510ce7c7ebb73 4f72bdb2e340f297c5c88a3433bf1700a010f721 refs/heads/master\0 report-status side-band-64k agent=git/2.20.1
12:47:39.998420 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> 0000
12:47:39.998841 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0035shallow 67769ed9405583783a372dc7731d5c1be8801a6300954a902e3cdd3c06ba7fe9aa0345e510ce7c7ebb73 4f72bdb2e340f297c5c88a3433bf1700a010f721 refs/heads/master\0 report-status side-band-64k agent=git/2.20.10000
12:47:39.998986 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git pack-objects --all-progress-implied --revs --stdout --thin --delta-base-offset --progress --shallow
12:47:40.007547 git.c:418               trace: built-in: git pack-objects --all-progress-implied --revs --stdout --thin --delta-base-offset --progress --shallow
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 530 bytes | 530.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
12:47:40.202197 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> 0000
12:47:40.202196 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< PACK ...
12:47:41.680994 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \1000eunpack ok0019ok refs/heads/master0000
12:47:41.681027 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< 0000
12:47:41.681108 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< unpack ok
12:47:41.681132 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< ok refs/heads/master
12:47:41.681148 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0000
12:47:41.681153 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> 0000
To https://gitlab/root/xxx.git
   4a902e3..4f72bdb  master -> master
```

The long parts seems to be `run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git-remote-https` and `git<PACK ...`.

This command was used in a `depth=2 git clone`.

**Note**: The first `push` is always fast (seems to be between 1 or 2 seconds), and the subsequents ones are mostly between 3 and 4 seconds. I tried to put a `sleep` between my pushes, but the duration isn't changing, so i guess it's not an issue from my code.

Here is the output of my *first* push:

```
12:46:16.834461 git.c:418               trace: built-in: git push https://root:password@gitlab/root/xxx.git
12:46:16.836817 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git-remote-https https://root:password@gitlab/root/xxx.git https://root:password@gitlab/root/xxx.git
12:46:17.307690 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< # service=git-receive-pack
12:46:17.307951 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0000
12:46:17.308003 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 6725c964319de48c963746e976a97634f0ee0e7c refs/heads/master\0report-status report-status-v2 delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta push-options object-format=sha1 agent=git/2.33.1.gl3
12:46:17.308024 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0000
12:46:17.309205 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
12:46:17.309223 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> 0000
12:46:17.309271 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git send-pack --stateless-rpc --helper-status --thin --progress https://root:password@gitlab/root/xxx.git/ --stdin
12:46:17.312085 git.c:418               trace: built-in: git send-pack --stateless-rpc --helper-status --thin --progress https://root:password@gitlab/root/xxx.git/ --stdin
12:46:17.313673 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
12:46:17.313707 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0000
12:46:17.313722 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 6725c964319de48c963746e976a97634f0ee0e7c refs/heads/master\0report-status report-status-v2 delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta push-options object-format=sha1 agent=git/2.33.1.gl3
12:46:17.314002 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0000
12:46:17.316186 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> shallow 67769ed9405583783a372dc7731d5c1be8801a63
12:46:17.316209 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> 6725c964319de48c963746e976a97634f0ee0e7c 6665f070f909ed946bf8223516f69691c15e9c29 refs/heads/master\0 report-status side-band-64k agent=git/2.20.1
12:46:17.316316 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> 0000
12:46:17.316423 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0035shallow 67769ed9405583783a372dc7731d5c1be8801a6300956725c964319de48c963746e976a97634f0ee0e7c 6665f070f909ed946bf8223516f69691c15e9c29 refs/heads/master\0 report-status side-band-64k agent=git/2.20.10000
12:46:17.316509 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git pack-objects --all-progress-implied --revs --stdout --thin --delta-base-offset --progress --shallow
12:46:17.318598 git.c:418               trace: built-in: git pack-objects --all-progress-implied --revs --stdout --thin --delta-base-offset --progress --shallow
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 521 bytes | 173.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
12:46:17.339570 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< PACK ...
12:46:17.339830 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> 0000
[03/May/2022 12:46:17] "POST /api/getStatus/ HTTP/1.1" 200 854
12:46:18.029134 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< \1000eunpack ok0019ok refs/heads/master0000
12:46:18.029164 pkt-line.c:80           packet:     sideband< 0000
12:46:18.029277 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< unpack ok
12:46:18.029285 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< ok refs/heads/master
12:46:18.029293 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git< 0000
12:46:18.029297 pkt-line.c:80           packet:          git> 0000
To https://gitlab/root/xxx.git
   6725c96..6665f07  master -> master
```

The duration of the `GIT_DIR` part seems to be faster, and the `git< PACK ...` is almost instant.

***Edit 2:***

It appeared that it was simply a performance issue from my server, but i think that @torek answer can help people searching about this subject, so i'm marking it as accepted.

Comment: Are the many commits that you make in a (possibly linear) history, or do you rewrite history on each commit?

Comment: @j6t The users are uploading files from the website, then they get pushed to Gitlab if they don't already exists inside the repo. Finally, i'm getting the Artifact generated by Gitlab for each file the user asked for. So the pushing part is only new files pushed to Gitlab, so i guess i'm not rewriting history.

Comment: Post the output of the push command, or even better, of all the commands.

Comment: @j6t Added the output of the push command. Git add and commit aren't outputting anything, and git rev-parse is only showing the commit hash. Thanks for trying to help !

Comment: You say that you change just one file, commit that, then push the commit. I am curious why that would push 191 objects. The cited scenario would push just the commit, the new file, the root tree object, and one object per additional directory level that is involved.

Comment: In which of the phases during the push do you see slow operation? Before "Enumerating objects" even begins (this is an important clue!! Be accurate when you answer this!)? Or later, during "Enumerating objects"? "Compressing objects"? "Writing objects"?

Comment: @j6t The long parts seems to be before Enumerating Objects, and during Writing Objects. The rest is almost instant. In my program, i'm doing all the add/commits, then doing the push using each of the commit sha, maybe that's the reason why there is that much objects ?

Comment: Use `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE2=2 git push origin $variable1:master` to see where the time is spent. My guess is that you have a large number of branches and tags that are negotiated.

Comment: @j6t i just tried the command, but does nothing with git-X=2, so i tried with git-x= true, i'm adding the output to my original post

Comment: @j6t also my first output was an issue from my code, the number of objects was incorrect. There is now 6/8 objects.

Comment: The trace output shows no unsurprising slowdowns. All commands finish within a few seconds. That is expected, I would say, when the peer is a web server.

Comment: @j6t well, i'd like the pushes to take 1/2 seconds like the first one, and not 3/4 seconds like the subsequents ones. It seems that gitlab-runner is taking all ressources from my machine, which makes the next pushes slower, so i don't think there is a solution apart from trying on a more powerful server...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

My guess is that you're letting GitLab use a shallow clone, which normally makes things faster, but in this case it's making things *much* slower.

#### Long

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11411662/nicolas-duvoisin) is probably the key comment:

> The long parts seems to be before Enumerating Objects, and during Writing Objects. The rest is almost instant.

A lot of this gets into the weeds of Git internals, which may change at any time without warning.  It's therefore unwise to depend too much on these.  Still, here's what's going on:

- A Git *repository* is mostly made up of two databases.  One database holds Git *objects*, and the other holds names: *refs* or *references*.  The objects are numbered (by hash ID or *object ID*, OID).  The refs turn human-usable names, such as `refs/heads/main` for branch `main`, into OIDs, with just one OID being stored per name.
- The OIDs are universal: each object has a unique OID, and all Gits everywhere number identical objects identically.  This means that any two Git repositories can meet—whether it's for the first time, or for the *n*<sup>th</sup> with a large value of *n*—and yet one can nearly instantly find out whether the *other* repository has some object, just by handing over the object's ID.  The sending Git lists out certain key OIDs, and the receiving Git responds with an "I have that" or "I want that" response.
- The next thing we need is complicated technically, but possibly easy enough to visualize or understand.  A *commit* object contains known metadata values, including a list of *parent* commits and one (single) *tree* object.  A *tree* object consists of repeated tuples giving component names, object types (or "modes"), and object IDs.  The objects listed *in* a tree are generally either another tree, or a *blob* object.  A blob object represents a file's content: the *name* of that file is produced by stringing together the names of tree objects that led from a commit to that blob.

  The parent(s) of any given commit are commits that existed at the time the commit itself was made.  Commits are made one at a time.  This means there cannot be cycles in the connections from commit to commit: if commit `H` links backwards to commit `G`, commit `G` cannot link forwards to commit `H` because `H` did not exist when `G` was made.  `G` can link back to still-earlier commits, but those cannot link forwards to `G` or `H`.

  Similarly, a tree object may not refer to itself, nor may any sub-tree within the tree object refer back to the tree object or any sub-tree that's "above" the sub-tree that is doing the referring.  That is, if tree OID `9876543` exists, none of its entries can refer to object `9876543`, and none of its subtrees—say, `5566778`—can refer to `9876543` either.  So there cannot be loops in any set of trees found by starting at a commit.  These rules mean that a tree is literally a *tree*, which is a subset of a DAG: see [What's the difference between the data structure Tree and Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7423401/1256452)

  (Blob objects represent file contents, which are opaque to Git at this level: Git does not have to examine them, and does not do so.)

  The end result of all of this is that the commits themselves form a Directed Acyclic Graph or DAG.  Meanwhile, the top level *tree* object within each commit forms a tree of tree objects.  So we have a DAG of trees, or DAG of DAGs, however you would like to refer to it; such a composition is itself a DAG.  (Note that commits can re-use top level or sub-level trees from earlier commits: that's perfectly fine here as it does not break the DAG rules.)

  (Atop all of this, we can have *annotated tag* objects, which store the hash ID of one *target object*.  Because they're limited to a single target, and Git's hash ID computation rules forbid loops, these just add a few leads-into-an-object nodes to the overall DAG-of-DAGs.  They add a little bit of complexity to a visualization, but do nothing to mess with the overall DAGginess.)

What all this boils down to, in the end, is that we have this overall graph structure with constraints: directionality and a lack of cycles.  Any such DAG has a *reachability* property: that is, starting from some node in the graph, there may be other nodes in the graph that we *can* reach, and there may be other nodes in the graph that we *cannot* reach, by following the one-way connections: commit `b789abc` has parent `a123456`, so `a123456` is *reachable from* `b789abc`.  As there are no cycles, this by definition means that `b789abc` is *not* reachable from `a123456`.  (You cannot, however, infer the reverse: if node X is not reachable from node Y, that does not mean that Y is reachable from X.  Perhaps W or Z reaches both X and Y, but X and Y are merely siblings in a tree, for instance.)

To this, we ***normally*** add one more constraint: a Git repository never has a "hole" in it.  By this, I mean that if we have some node *in* the graph, we must always have *every node reachable from that node*.  If `a123456` is the parent of `b789abc`, and we have `b789abc`, we must also have `a123456`.  This in turn means that we must have the entire *snapshot of* `a123456`.  If `a123456` has a parent commit, we must have the entire snapshot of *that* commit too, and so on.

Note the emphasis on the word *normally* above.  When this is the case, if we are the sender and we're doing a `git push`, we can often tell, just by knowing which commits are the latest commits in the *receiving* Git repository, *everything* about those commits.  That is, if we have new commit `b789abc` and they have its parent `a123456`, *we already have `a123456` ourselves*.  We also have *everything reachable from* `a123456`.  So we know everything about every file they have, at least as far as `a123456` *and* all of its ancestry is concerned.

This gives a sending Git a huge leg up: it tells the receiving Git *I can send you commit `b789abc`, would you like it?*  The receiving Git might answer with *I already have `b789abc`*, in which case we know everything we need to know about the receiving Git, or it might say *Yes I'd like that*.  If it says the latter, we, as the sending Git, must now offer the parent `a123456`.  They will either respond with *I already have it* or *please send it*, after which we'll offer its parent(s), and so on.

At some point, we either run out of commits to send—they have nothing and we must send *every* object—or we hit some commit that they have, which means that they have that commit *and every earlier commit* and we, the sender, now know precisely what files they have as well.  So we can do a great job of sending them *just* the commits they need, and *just* the files they need *for* those commits, *and* we can compress those files knowing what earlier versions of those files that they already have.

Note that there's a big overall assumption here, that CPU time is cheap, but network bandwidth is expensive.  We use this OID-exchange process to find what they already have, then we prepare the new objects and compress them against the known old objects.  This ("compressing objects") part *can* take a lot of time, depending on how fast our own computation is.  But it's usually pretty quick because typically we're sending just one or a few commits, with just one or a few new or modified files each, so there's not much to compress.  We then send those objects, and that part is as slow as the network is, but if we did a good job of compressing, we don't have to send many objects *and* we've compressed them very well against other objects they already have.

Note, though, that if we `git push` the current (`HEAD`) commit, we *must* send them *all* parent commits back to the point where our history and their history join up.  This maintains the "completeness" or "lack of holes" property.  So your code here:

> ```
> variable1 = git rev-parse HEAD  # Storing last commit hash into a variable
> # Pushing only one specific commit to (maybe) make it faster
> git push $variable1:master
> ```

does no good; you could just `git push HEAD:master`, or if your current branch name *is* `master` on your (sender's) "side", you could just `git push master`.

I mentioned above that a repository is made up of *two* databases.  The process I've described so far is all about updating the *object* database.  That's the really important one, because the names database is mainly there to help puny humans: all the *machine* needs is the raw hash IDs.  *Git* won't go nuts trying to tell the difference between `720100ac47678fa31f0844a413f05bd0305d179f` and `720100ac47678fae1f0844a413f05bd0305d179f`, the way humans would (I made one tiny change here: can you spot it?).  But we need to update the names database too, so following the above, the *sending* Git will send either a polite request, or a forceful command (or perhaps more than one of one or both, with different names in the blanks):

- Please, if it's OK, create or update your name _______ to hold ID _______; or
- Set your name _______ to hold _______!

(There's a third kind, a *conditionally forceful* update, where the sender says *I think your name _______ holds _______.  If so, set it to _______!*  That's the `--force-with-lease` option, and it just enables a safer way to do the command.)

The receiving Git obeys, or doesn't, at its pleasure according to various rules (hosting servers generally add a bunch of control rules atop the super-simple ones that out-of-the-box Git provides).  The sender's job is just to provide the names and hash IDs, along with the polite requests or forceful commands, and take back the reply from the receiving Git: "OK" or "rejected", along with any side messages that might come from a hosting server, e.g., telling a user that he does not have access rights to set that name.  The sender then reports the result(s) to the person or process that ran `git push`, and updates any remote-tracking names for the `git push` operations that actually succeeded.

So, if you have several things to send, you *can* send them all together:

```
git push origin master mybranch:theirbranch
```

for instance.  This has your sending Git collect the OIDs for `master` and `mybranch` on your side, send any commits and supporting objects required to their Git, then ask (politely) that they set their `master` and `theirbranch` to the OIDs your Git found for your `master` and `yourbranch`.

#### Things that go wrong: too many names and shallow clones

That's the *normal* process.  Now let's see what might work to confound it.

First, some (not all) existing sending and receiving processes will sometimes go through *every* name they have in their names database.  For repositories with tens of thousands of tag names, for instance, this can take a lot of time.  This happens well before the "counting objects" phase even starts.  If you have a network monitor or tracer, you will see a lot of data coming from the receiver, listing out all their branch and tag names and corresponding hash IDs, even though the sender doesn't really need all of that.  There are some technical improvements here that are being worked-on in the C version of Git, but they've been in progress for a long time (multiple years now I think) and aren't there yet.  If this *is* a problem, the simplest solution is to prune back a lot of the names, but this generally requires archiving, or at least renaming, the existing repository and making a new one (because some hash IDs will be findable only through the old names, and you probably don't want to lose those forever).

More importantly, go back to the word *normally* I put in bold-italics above.  We can make a kind of Git clone, which Git calls a *shallow* clone, in which the usual constraints—that there are no "holes" in the graph—are deliberately violated.  To implement this, Git writes certain commit hash IDs into a file, saying *this commit is assumed to exist, but we don't have it, so we don't know anything about it*.

When a *receiving* Git is shallow, the *sending* Git has a problem, and when a *sending* Git is shallow, the *sending* Git has a problem.   This means shallow clones are OK as one-time things but are a bad idea for ongoing work, where you're going to run `git fetch` ("get more objects from some other repository") or `git push` ("send objects to some other repository").  In particular, the normal assumption, that if someone has commit `b789abc` whose parent is `a123456`, then they not only have `a123456` but also every earlier commit and therefore every version of every file up to that point, just breaks down entirely.

Because of the have/want protocol that senders use when sending *to* receivers, though, a depth-*two* shallow clone is much better for doing `git push` to a full (non-shallow) clone than is a depth-1 clone.  The extra commit in the "deeper" clone allows the sender to understand better what the receiver has, even if the sender doesn't have everything needed to do the best possible compression.

The *best* sending result is achieved when you have a full clone in the first place, but if you're going to make a shallow clone, then commit and push, start with at least a depth-2 clone.  CI systems often use a depth-1 shallow clone on purpose, but usually have knobs to adjust the depth, or to make a full (non-shallow) clone.  Some depth compromise (other than just 2) may work best for you case; it's hard to say without actual testing.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailled answer ! I'm not sure to understand everything, but that's starting to get clearer for me. I've added an output for a depth-2 clone, so you can maybe confirm what you said, or maybe find another issue !

Comment: At this point, the slow part is waiting for the server to start up the Git process. Is the server a fast Linux box, or a slow Windows system? Note also that you've gone from `Compressing objects: 100% (109/109), done.` to just 4 objects, so you've saved a lot of object work (down 105 from the 109 before).

Comment: It's a linux server, i have a Docker using Gitlab and Gitlab-runner images. My server isn't the quickest, but it's not the worst (still got 8gb ram, running in localhost only). I know about the compressing part, i had an issue in my previous code. But that's still slow (as you can see on the `GIT_TRACE` part).

Comment: Which part is server-side and slow ?

Comment: Ah, Docker can take some time to spin up, depending on many things. See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/cuqr67/realistic_startup_times_for_container/) for instance. To make this sort of thing faster, keep the docker instance running and serving, rather than starting it up each time.

Comment: My containers are started since a while now, and i'm restarting them only when i need it (during development phase). It seems to be slow even after serverals hours of serving.

Comment: OK, then I don't know why it's going so slowly over on the server. Perhaps you can instrument the web server over there to see what is making it so slow.

Comment: I'm putting your answer as accepted, since that's probably what people will search for when they get to my question. In my case, that's certainly a performance issue from my server. Thanks for your detailled answer !

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: This answer works for *ssh* connections. Since the question talk about *https* the @torek answer is more appropriate.

---

One way to increase the speed is, to use ssh `ControlMaster` option. It avoid ssh to reopen a connection each time.

The *ControlMaster* option from `ssh_config` man page :

> Enables the sharing of multiple sessions over a single network connection.  When set to yes, ssh(1)
> will listen for connections on a control socket specified using the ControlPath argument. Additional sessions can connect to this socket using the same ControlPath with ControlMaster set to no (the default). These sessions will try to reuse the master instance's network connection rather
> than initiating new ones, but will fall back to connecting normally if the control socket does not exist, or is not listening.

For example in my ~/.ssh/config I have:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/mux-%r@%h_%p
ControlPersist 15m
```

Comment: I'm actually using HTTPS, sorry i didn't specify it. I'm adding it to my post, thanks for your answer however, since this will probably help some people !